# What does a superscript plus sign mean in integral notation?

Tags: integration, notation

In the following paper, there is some notation which I don't understand:

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hoong_Lau/publication/222409130_Evaluation_of_time-varying_availability_in_multi-echelon_spare_parts_systems_with_passivation/links/0deec528b55f2b9097000000/Evaluation-of-time-varying-availability-in-multi-echelon-spare-parts-systems-with-passivation.pdf

Equations 17, 19 and 20 have expressions in brackets followed by a superscript plus sign.

I can interpret this one of two ways (at least):

- "The positive part of", i.e. max(x, 0), or
- Ignore (set to zero) the entire integrand where the expression is less than zero.

Given the context of the rest of the paper, I am inclined to the second interpretation, but would appreciate further input, particularly if you have an alternative interpretation.

Comment: It is the positive part (hence the exponential is $1$ for negative arguments). Had the entire integrand be canceled, another function would have been used as a factor to the integrand, possibly denoted as $(x\ge0)$.

Comment: Re-reading a pertinent part of the paper more thoroughly, I concur.